# Sine-Wave Fit To Time Series: Confidence Limits For Non-Normal Data

Tags: confidence-interval, error, fitting, uncertainty

I have a time series that I know to be made up of several sine waves:

$F(t)=C + \sum_{i=1}^NA_i\sin(2\pi f_it+p_i)$

Where $C$ is a normalization constant, and $(A_i,f_i,p_i)$ are the amplitude, frequency, and phase of the $i^{th}$ sine wave.

I have already fit all parameters to my time series and am satisfied with the results; I just need to know how to get confidence limits for them. The time series has non-normal errors in its measurements (in my field the term is red noise), so apparently I cannot use traditional methods to find the 1-$\sigma$ uncertainties of my parameter fits.

The method that I normally use is by using constant $\chi^2$ boundaries as confidence limits. Can I do something similar in the case of non-normal errors?

Comment: How did you fit the parameters?  Did you explicitly model the "red noise"?  If not, perhaps you ought to, because in the process you usually obtain the information you need to compute the covariance matrix of the parameters, from which confidence intervals are derived.

Comment: Again, the method I am familiar with is constant $\chi^2$ boundaries as confidence limits. I thought that the standard equations relating covariance matrices to parameter uncertainties were invalid in the case of non-normal errors? In other words, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I'm simply asking a question: *how did you fit the parameters*?  And in particular, *how did you account for the red noise when you did so?*  If you didn't, then whatever method you're using to construct confidence intervals is likely incorrect.

Comment: I used $\chi^2$ minimization. No, I did not account for red noise in the fit, nor do I know what that means. Your final statement is the entirety of my original question: how do I account for non-normal errors when constructing confidence intervals?

Comment: You don't.  You have to back up and account for the non-normal errors in the original model and in the fitting procedure; you don't just back into a confidence interval by starting with a fit based on a different model!